# Why does http request fail when running from rake task in a thread?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rake, rake-task

I am trying to figure out why the following code does not work. The response is not printed out and from other research the request fails.

```
task :test_me  do
    t1 = Thread.new do
      puts 'start'
      uri = URI.parse("http://google.com/")
      response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
      puts response.inspect # this line not getting printed
    end
    # puts t1.value
end
```

However if I run the following

```
task :test_me  do
    t1 = Thread.new do
      puts 'start'
      uri = URI.parse("http://google.com/")
      response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
      puts response.inspect # this line is printing because of puts below
    end
    puts t1.value
end
```

All is well

Note there are probably many ways to restructure this code, but I have dumbed down the example as far as possible and it's extracted from a [gem](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-ruby) so I don't have too much control over it.

If I can get a solid reason to why this is not working from a rake task I could potentially go back to them with a PR.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is because you are not calling `join` after the `Thread` block. However, when you use `.value`, it will automatically join the thread for you (as documented [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread.html#method-i-value))

Try this:

```
task :test_me  do
    t1 = Thread.new do
      puts 'start'
      uri = URI.parse("http://google.com/")
      response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
      puts response.inspect
    end
    t1.join
end
```

Comment: Question ... so why would this work if I didn't run it in a task? If I ran it in the console I wouldn't need the join at the end

Comment: Because in a rake task, the process ends the execution (and quits) before your thread has the chance to complete its execution (thus never printing the result). When you run this code in the console, the console process doesn't end until you manually quit.

Comment: So, when you `join` the thread with your main process, it will wait the thread to end to continue its execution.